# Add pathloss to signal

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis

I simulate a transmission channel in Matlab. I want to add pathloss ($PL=100\textrm{ dB}$) to the signal TX.
here is the code edited

```
PL=100; 
snrdb=10; 
snr=10^(snrdb/10); 

L=length(TX1); 
REC1=TX1+sqrt(1/(2*snr))*(randn(1,L)+1i*randn(1,L));
```

can anyone help regarding the pathloss effect!

Answer (score 1):

To simulate 100dB pathloss from the transmitter to the receiver, you can do

```
tx = .....; % generate the TX signal
PL_db = 100; PL_lin = 10^(PL_db/10);
rx = tx / sqrt(PL_lin);  % the amplitude is scaled with the square root of the power scaling.

% add some noise at the receiver, according to the SNR
```

Comment: @farfella you can consider clicking the checkmark to indicate the qeustion has been resolved.